# Prevent the space key from closing confirmation box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a website which shows a table to the user. In one column the table contains input boxes where the user can enter notes. Below each of those input boxes there is a save button for saving the entered notes to a database. One requirement of the website was that it automatically refreshes the table contents every 30 seconds.

Now the problem is that when a user types in a note in one of the input boxes, it sometimes can happen that the table refreshes exactly before the user presses the save button (or before he even finished typing the note).

As a solution I tried checking if any of the input boxes currently has the focus and if that is the case, a confirmation box will appear and ask the user if he wants to refresh the table or of he first wants to finish typing in the input box. Here is the code for my solution:

```
setInterval(function ()
{
    var canRefresh = true;
    var noteInputs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="note_"]');

    for (var i = 0; i < noteInputs.length; i++) {
        if ($(noteInputs[i]).is(':focus')) {
            canRefresh = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (canRefresh || confirm('Do you want to refresh the table?')) {
        //Refresh the table
    }

}, 30000)
```

Unfortunately, there is one problem with this solution.
While it actually does work fine, I realized that it can easily happen that the user accidentally closes the confirmation box almost immediately by pressing the space key while typing a note.

Therefore, is there any way to either disable the space key for the confirmation box or is there any better solution?

Comment: There's no way to change the bahaviour of the `confirm()` dialog.  You'll need to implement your own dialog/modal (jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap or another plugin) which doesn't close (or is configured not to close) on space.  Or maybe use something less intrusive like a toaster popup (eg https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr)

Comment: Don't use `confirm()` I think that's annoying, like `alert()` and `prompt()`. I would rather use something like bootstrap modal

Comment: Use bootstrap modal instead, it's more flexible to customize , and you can prevent it from closing by adding `data-backdrop="static"` as attribute to modal.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into bootstrap modal!

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval()` returns an identifier you can use later as parameter to `clearInterval()`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval